# htaccess rewrite part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I found similar examples here on Stack Overflow, but can't get it to work.

I'm trying to rewrite a URL from

`http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5vc`

to:

`http://www.example.com/login&return=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5vc`

I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return(.*)$ /login?return$1 [R=301,L]
```

But as I said, I can't get it to work. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as **first rule** in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?option=com_users&view=([^&\s]+)&return=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1?return=%2 [R=301,L]
```

You cannot match `QUERY_STRING` using `RewriteRule`.